# Secure Api data React Client Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, authentication

I have a react js  client app (using create-react-app) in which I fetch some API sensitive data (elasticsearch is my backend, and there is no protection except a firewall). I’m using 0auth authentication to authenticate the users before they use the app. (As seen on internet tutorials)
However, I’m almost sure it isn’t secure at all having a client side authentication. A hacker could just change my javascript/React code where it evaluates if the user is logged in, and get the app sensitive data.
How to effectively protect my app then? ( currently, I’m not willing to add protection to my back end.)
And also, I’m using environment variables for api keys, how do I protect them?

I apologize if this seems to newbie, I’m still new to react and client side only apps.

Comment: Are you minifying your javascript?

Comment: `A hacker could just change my javascript/React code where it evaluates if the user is logged in, and get the app sensitive data` -- usually this is returned by the API and you'd authenticate on each request. The UI should only be pivoting based on the response from the server. Example (UI - *does user have this privilege?*, API : *yes/no*)

Comment: @MarkC. Hm currently no, but I’m willing in the future (still in development). Im not seeing how it would help protecting the app! Thank you

Comment: @MarkC. Hm I see, I was wondering it there was another way to solve this but I think that’s the only secure way to go. Thank vou very much!

Comment: @MarkC. Server side rendering is not  an option?